# What is the difference between an Aryl Halide and a Vinyl Halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, halides

Are aryl halides a type of vinyl halide? From my knowledge, when a Halogen atom is directly bonded to a doubly bonded carbon atom it is a Vinyl halide. When we look at halogen atom directly bonded to a benzene ring we see a similar thing. So are these terms never correlated? Also is Phenylic Halide a term which exists?

Comment: You are pretty much asking whether a benzene ring is a double bond. Well, in some ways they are similar, but in many ways they aren't; I'm sure you can come up with examples. The same applies to aryl / vinyl halides.

Comment: Ooh that is a good way of putting it and I do realise the stupidity in my question now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, aryl halides are not a type of vinyl halides.**

A compound is called an aryl halide when it contains a halogen group directly attached to an aromatic system. For example,

[image: Aryl halides]

Whereas a compound is called a vinyl halide when it contains a halogen group directly attached to a doubly bonded carbon atom. For example,

[image: Vinyl halides]

The double bonds in an aromatic system are not the same as the aliphatic double bonds. They differ quite a bit in terms of electron density and thus there derivatives behave very differently is many circumstances.

The term phenylic halide doesn't exist but a very similar term phenyl halide exists which is a subset of aryl halides family.

An aryl halide can be called a phenyl halide when the aromatic system of the compound is specifically the phenyl system($\ce{-C6H5}$). For example,

[image: Phenyl halides]